# Rails 3, what's the best act as tree behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, tree

So I'm looking for a gem that will bring some tree behavior to the pages model.

From what I can see there are quite a few, I was wondering what other people thought.

If there any great ones or and dodgy ones to avoid.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry), it's remarkably efficient.

Comment: Went this this over the other because it has excellent documentation.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [Closure Tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree). His author introduces good resources and reasons for it [here](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/hierarchical-tagging-with-rails-3-and-closure-trees-1131.html).

Answer (score 2):

check out here

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting

I prefer awesome_nested_set

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the most popular is AwesomeNestedSet https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

It has categories ordering system, what is missing in others and all standart functions. Setup is pretty well docummented

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented `acts_as_tree` successfully for some threaded comments, but am not impressed by its performance-handling. It was very simple to implement, though.

By default, it now queries the database once for every node in the tree. I suspect with some clever settings and some optimisation this can be solved though, but, out of the box: not too impressed.